# Named Parameters in ValueTuple.Create (2)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

In an other [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178757/named-parameters-in-valuetuple-create) i asked about named parameters in ValueTuple.Create. But since my example code wasn't true to my problem I didn't get the answer I wanted. So here we go again:

First demo data:

```
public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; } = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category(){Name="Beverages", ID=001},
            new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=002},
        }.AsQueryable();

        public IQueryable<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product{Name="Cola",  CategoryID=001},
            new Product{Name="Tea",  CategoryID=001},
            new Product{Name="Mustard", CategoryID=002},
            new Product{Name="Pickles", CategoryID=002},
        }.AsQueryable();

    }
```

**NOTE** `IQueryable`

Then to my problem:

```
    public static IEnumerable<(int CategoryId, string ProductName)> GetList()
    {
        var data = new Data();
        return
            (from category in data.Categories
                join prod in data.Products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
                select ValueTuple.Create(category.ID, prod.Name)).OrderBy(e => e.Item2);
    }
```

But if I want a result sorted by Product name I have to use `OrderBy(e => e.Item2)`. Can I somehow get rid of the Item1 and Item2 names in my Order by

Since I have an IQueryable interface I have to use `ValueTuple.Create`

Comment: LINQ doesn't support tuples (yet), sorry. You'll have to settle for something like  `from ... orderby prod.Name select new { CategoryID = category.ID, ProductName = prod.Name }).AsEnumerable().Select(o => (o.CategoryID, o.ProductName))`. The final tuple construction needs a switch to object LINQ. (Note that you definitely want to push the `orderby` in the query where possible -- sorting the constructed tuples is potentially vastly less efficient, depending on the provider.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workarround,: I could make a type case:

```
    public static IEnumerable<(int CategoryId, string ProductName)> GetList()
    {
        var data = new Data();
        return
            (from category in data.Categories
                join prod in data.Products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
                select ((int CategoryId, string ProductName))ValueTuple.Create(category.ID, prod.Name)).OrderBy(e => e.ProductName);
    }
```

Comment: Note that, while this will parse, not all LINQ providers will support `ValueTuple.Create`. (In fact, almost none will, except LINQ to Objects.) For those that do, the cast will be transparent, so that bit's OK.